# Return (row, column) tuple given a pixel (x,y) position

Tags: python, tkinter

Python 3:

I need to create a function that returns a (row, column) tuple given a pixel (x,y) position.
this will be used to determine which row/column a pixel is in

```
Given variables:
width: the width of the canvas in pixels

height: the height of the canvas in pixels

cols: the number of columns

rows: the number of rows

Parameters:
(x,y): a tuple containing the x and y positions of a pixel

Returns:

(row, column)
```

Eg: a 300x300 pixel canvas with 3x3 rows/columns:

```
pixel_function((30,37)) -> (0,0)
```

This should return 0,0 as the pixel is in a row and column 0.

Comment: Have you tried something like this?: `def pixel_function(x, y): return (x//(width/columns), y//(height/rows))`

Answer (score 1):

`// operator` will work for you

```
 def pixel_function(pixel):
        row, col = 3, 3
        canvas_x, canvas_y = 300, 300
        return int(pixel[0] // (canvas_x / row)), int(pixel[1] // (canvas_y / col))
    
    
    print(pixel_function((30,37)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean division should help you.

For example 178 // 100 = 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to determine the number of pixels in each row and column

You can get this by dividing height by the number of rows and width by the number of columns

Then you need to determine which row your pixel lies in and then in which column

```
num_of_pixels_per_row = height/rows
num_of_pixels_per_col = width/cols
# for a given (x,y)
# // operator gives you the quotient from the division
pixel_row = y // num_of_pixels_per_row
pixel_col = x // num_of_pixels_per_col
```

Comment: Should use y for row and x for column.